# Webgl: Water effect in 2D

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I am rendering a simple polygon using triangulation in webgl. Now I want it to look like blue water, with effects like ripple or refraction. Since I have no mesh, so I can work with fragment shader only. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use several textures, like bluish for water, black-and-white caustics for caustics and stone texture for floor. Then write fragment shader that would distort textures over time and simulate different effects you're up to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for distortion part.. any leads?

Comment: Try searching some of the effects on shadertoy.com or so. Any kind of distortion with sin(time) or cos(time) with addition of noise textures, anything that might help, but that's just playing with shader until you reach the result that you're satisfied with.

Answer (score 0):

I put together this VFX shadertoy [Water2D demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mls3DH) a few years back. It doesn't do reflection, and the camera is directly overhead looking straight down but maybe it will help you get started.

```
const float speed     = 0.2;                      
const float frequency = 8.0;                  

vec2 shift( vec2 p )
{                        
    float d = iGlobalTime*speed;
    vec2 f = frequency * (p + d);
    vec2 q = cos( vec2(                        
       cos(f.x-f.y)*cos(f.y),                       
       sin(f.x+f.y)*sin(f.y) ) );                   
    return q;                                  
}                                             

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{                                 
    vec2 r = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;                      
    vec2 p = shift( r );             
    vec2 q = shift(r + 1.0);                        
    float amplitude = 2.0 / iResolution.x;   
    vec2 s = r + amplitude * (p - q);
    s.y = 1. - s.y; // flip Y axis for ShaderToy
    fragColor = texture( iChannel0, s );
}
```